# Search for a folder name inside an Aptana Studio 3 project

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to find a folder with a specific name inside an Aptana Studio 3 project. Finding a file is easy enough, however, I only know the name of a folder I'm looking for.

Of course, I can open Windows Explorer and use it to search for a folder name, but I want to do this all in the IDE. Is this possible?

#### Example

For example, say my project is structured like this:

[image: App Explorer panel in Aptana Studio 3]

And I would want to find the folder named "testing". Can I use any of the built-in search tools to find it, or would I have to use the search functionality of Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Project names are in the Project Explorer Window. It's over in the left hand side. For many of the functional things get aptana_studio_beginners_guide.pdf it is very helpful for getting up to speed quickly. I couldn't snip an image I don't have a high enough level. Please Google the file name it should help you it is step by step and I found it very useful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've improved my question to make it more clear what I'm asking.